# javascript variable undefined despite having been defined

Tags: javascript, variables, mouseevent, undefined

I'm trying to get the mouse's position on an HTML5 canvas using this function:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

The function is called through an event listener (listening to the mousemove event) attached to the window DOM object.

I declared the initial values of mousePos as 0,0 in an object like so:

```
var engine = {
    canvas: document.getElementById('main'),
    mousePos: {x:0,y:0},
    ...
}
```

Whenever I move the mouse outside of the canvas and reload the page, the console reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mousePos is not defined
```

Since the window.mousemove event has not fired yet, the variable is undefined. But to me, it seems that before I use the variable for the first time, it is defined properly. Despite that, why do I still receive this error?

The rest of my code (including HTML): https://pastebin.com/03FZ2Q3L

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when u set window.onload = engine.init();  init is a function , mousePos inside init() is not this.mousePos ? because it is inside a function

Comment: It looks like you're referring to a `mousePos` variable inside `init`, as well as in other places. You don't appear to have any such variable though, just a property with that name on the `engine` object. Try changing these references to `mousePos` to `engine.mousePos` instead

Comment: changing `mousePos = getMousePos(engine.canvas, evt);` to `engine.mousePos = getMousePos(...);` gave me even more errors.

Comment: update: it turns out you guys were right. there were many places inside the engine object where I didn't refer to mousePos as engine.mousePos, which was causing the errors. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some places in my code where I forgot to refer to the mousePos variables as engine.mousePos, because I forgot they were placed inside the engine object.

Example:

```
if(typeof mousePos.x !== undefined){ ... }
```

should be

```
if(typeof engine.mousePos.x !== undefined){ ... }
```

Thanks to everyone for the help